# C# - Creating a number generator with specific numbers written in textboxes

Tags: c#, loops, windows-forms-designer

Good day,

First, here is an image of the windows form: [image: WindowsForm]

So, of course I want to develope an application. One that generates a list of ID's for graves of a graveyard. It should display me the ID's in a `listbox`.
ID example: 
GTH - 1 - 1 - 1
GTH - 1 - 1 - 2

"GTH" is the value in the textbox right next to "Friedhof".
The other numbers should be numbers between the textboxes above.
As example: From(von) "1" till(bis) "9"

So the ID should be like: Friedhof - Feld - Reihe - Nr

Ignore the dropdownlists at the right side. So I don't know where to begin. I'm new to C#. Could you give me a code example, when I press the button "start" it should do a loop and write the ID's in the listbox.

I really only need to know how to begin...

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Friedhof_Generator
{
    public partial class frm_Grabnummer : Form
    {
        public frm_Grabnummer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ddl_Feld.Items.Add("Arabisch");
            ddl_Feld.Items.Add("Römisch");
            ddl_Feld.Items.Add("Alphabetisch");

            ddl_Reihe.Items.Add("Arabisch");
            ddl_Reihe.Items.Add("Römisch");
            ddl_Reihe.Items.Add("Alphabetisch");

            ddl_Nr.Items.Add("Arabisch");
            ddl_Nr.Items.Add("Römisch");
            ddl_Nr.Items.Add("Alphabetisch");
        }

        private void ddl_Feld_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void btn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I really only need to know how to begin..."* - That's a good question, but unfortunately not one that's really on-topic for this community.  When you have some specific code which demonstrates a specific problem you're trying to solve, we can help with that.  At the moment what you're looking for are introductory tutorials of how to learn C# WinForms development.  Google searches for things like "c# tutorials" or "c# winforms tutorials" or "c# windows forms tutorials" are where you would begin.

Comment: From(von) "1" till(bis) "9" - `Random rnd = new Random(); int rndNum = rnd.Next(int.Parse(field1.Text), int.Parse(field2.Text));` This will generate a random number and replace the `field1` and `field2` with your textboxs

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to get all possible combinations?
I've used nested loops because it is hopefully easier to understand.

Nested loops: For every value in the outer loop, every value in the inner loop will be executed.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
  {
    //do something...
  }
}
```

For i=0 the inner loop will be executed three times as for j=0; j=1 and j=2. Now i will be incremented by 1. And again the inner loop will be executed three times. This will be repeated until i >= 4.

Example (untested):

```
private int nFieldFrom = 0;
private int nFieldTo = 0;
private int nRowFrom = 0;
private int nRowTo = 0;
private int nNumberFrom = 0;
private int nNumberTo = 0;


    //Not necessary for the functionality but it is good to validate the user input
    private bool ValidateInput()
    {
       bool blnValid;

       if(!int.TryParse(FieldFrom.Text, out nFieldFrom)
          || !int.TryParse(FieldTo.Text, out nFieldTo)
          || !int.TryParse(RowFrom.Text, out nRowFrom)
          || !int.TryParse(RowTo.Text, out nRowTo)
          || !int.TryParse(NumberFrom.Text, out nNumberFrom)
          || !int.TryParse(NumberTo.Text, out nNumberTo))
        {
          blnValid = false;
        }    
        else
        {
          blnValid = true;
        }

      return blnValid;
    }

    private void btn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This list will contain all your ID's
        List<string> lstResults = new List<string>();

        //Every time the button is clicked the user input should be validated
        //GTH field = your 'Friedhof' field
        if(ValidateInput() && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(GTHField.Text))
        {
            for(int f = nFieldFrom; f <= nFieldTo; f++)
            {
                for(int r = nRowFrom; r <= nRowTo; r++)
                {
                    for(int n = nNumberFrom; n <= nNumberTo; n++)
                    {
                        lstResults.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}", GTHField.Text, f, r, n));
                    }
                }
            }

            lb_Ausgabe.DataSource = lstResults;
        }
        else
        {
            //error handling
            //for exmaple show a message box
            //MessageBox.Show("....");
        }
    }
```